# How can we check the file names using condition action

Tags: azure-logic-apps

My logic app trigger is when a file is created or modified (properties) so my share point path is shared documents/library---> these two folders are common for all the paths so on trigger i will give library name as Documents so if I uploaded the files in other path logic app will fail because the path is different so I think I want to given condition action so on condition action u will give the path as expression isequalto and on right hand box i wii will give true but it will execute false if I upload the file in what I want to the path

I was try to use condition action but it did not work

Comment: Please specify *did not work* and how you configured the condition

Answer (score 0):

Below are the 2 ways that you can try to achieve your requirement.

#### Way-1 :

Right after the trigger you can add condition connector where it checks for the folder rather that the whole path. Below is something how the flow looks like.

[image]

#### Way-2 :

You can directly select Folder from `Add new parameter` and mention the folder that you want the flow to get triggered.

[image]

Comment: But in my case one patha will maintain different files for suppose my path is shared documents/folder1/subfolder/2023/02/26/sourcefile1
My second file path is Shared Documents/folder1/subfolder/2023/02/26/sourcefile2
My third file path is Shared Documents/folder1/subfolder/2023/02/26/sourcefile3
If we observe till 26 paths is different but after that files names are different how can I implemented thae case

Comment: In that case you can use switch action and make it perform on folder path as this [image](https://i.imgur.com/XZsNj7M.png).

Comment: But I'm using two triggers in one logic app first  trigger is when a file is created or modified second one is recurrence so under recurrence there will be two actions under when a files is created or modified will have 3 actions so if the recurrence actions will trigger then when a file is created or modified actions also execute true' and when a file is created or modified actions will trigger recurrence actions also excecute successfully so our final motive is end of the day logic app is successful trigger if the files are uploaded or not logic app excute successfully no need to come failed

Comment: @VijayPodili It would be easy to diagnose if the flow is provided so try editing the question and add screenshots of your logic app

Comment: Thank you for your soulton but how can we implement below case share documents/folder1/2023/02/26/source document

Comment: Thank you for your soulton but how can we implement below case share documents/folder1/2023/02/26/source document--->first path when a file is created or modified.  share documents/new/folder1/solution file-->recurrence trigger second file. Shared documents/newfolder/2022/04/24/source file ---> when a file is created or modified trigger at the end of the day logic app is successful excute if the files are uploaded or not for all the actions evey file. Will maintain different timings

Comment: Above mentioned all the cases will be there in single logic app

Comment: You just need to mention the folder in the switch conditions till `documents/folder1/2023/02/26` or `documents/folder1/2023/02/25` or `documents/folder1/2023/02/24` and so on. refer  https://i.imgur.com/XZsNj7M.png.

Comment: Thanks Sweta you observe that paths are different on 4th comment first path is document/new/folder1/2022/02/23--->first path recurrence trigger. Shared documents/paths/folder2/2021/04/21---when a file is created or modified trigger second path .shared documents/parameters/folder3/source file ---recurrence trigger erd path and the recurrence trigger will trigger the logic app every day in a week and the time is 8am ist and. We have pass the paths in expression because they main files in every date so we have maintain expression like(contact(document/utcNow (yyyy))like that

Comment: In that case you can maintain the flow that mentioned in the answer with utc timings. However I hope that is different question from what you have mentioned in the question. You can raise a new question for that

Comment: Hope I have answered this question

Comment: Thank you Swetha but you suggest condition right it will not working if the file is uploaded in the exact path then also it will execute false statement

Comment: @James I hope you have tried the above conditions else add what you have tried with screenshots and what is not working. Also it would be great if you have achieved already and let Community know how you achieved this

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1182747/how-to-pass-two-folder-paths-in-when-a-file-is-cre?page=1&orderby=helpful&comment=answer-1180190#newest-answer-comment.          These is my exact work flow

Comment: Thank you Sweta these my work flow so now how can I compare the files using condition